# how to append www when subdomain exists in htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, routes, subdomain

I have a subdomain named abc.domain.com and if I try to open it using

```
http://www.abc.domain.com
```

it never opens however with

```
http://abc.domain.com
```

it works fine.

Please suggest how to redirect from **http://abc.domain.com** ==> **http://www.abc.domain.com**

Edit -------------------------

Here is my htaccess file code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteBase / 
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.domain\.com [NC]
 RewriteRule (.*) http://www.abc.domain.com/ [L,R=301]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: When you ping `www.abc.domain.com` what do you get?

Comment: I get server not found. 404.

Comment: It that case rewrite rules can do nothing. You need to setup DNR records and `VirtualHost`.